# Managing Shell Tasks

Tags: linux, shell, task

I am writing the following shell script:

```
perf stat taskset -c 0 runspec  & perf stat taskset -c 1 runspec 

perf stat taskset -c 0 runspec  & perf stat taskset -c 1 runspec
```

As seen, each line consists of two tasks submitted to two different cpu's. I want a way to guarantee that the second line "the second two tasks" will not start executing until the first two tasks complete successfully. Is there away to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `wait` for the PID of the background process.

```
perf stat taskset -c 0 runspec &
pid=$!
perf stat taskset -c 1 runspec 
wait $pid

perf stat taskset -c 0 runspec &
pid=$!
perf stat taskset -c 1 runspec
wait $pid
```

Clearly, this would be more elegant with a bit of additional refactoring.  Perhaps like this:

```
parallel () {
    local pid
    # Danger: unquoted interpolation
    $1 &
    pid=$!
    # Danger: unquoted interpolation
    $2
    wait $pid
}

prun () {
    perf stat taskset -c $1 runspec
}

parallel "prun 0" "prun 1"
parallel "prun 0" "prun 1"
```

Notice that the `parallel` function interpolates `$1` and `$2` without double quotes.  For this toy demonstration, that is harmless, but if you end up needing to pass in quoted strings as arguments, you will need a more elaborate solution.

Comment: The second half of this answer doesn't work. Try running it. It issues the commands `"prun 0"` and `"prun 1"` (with quotes) which don't call the `prun` function. You could use `eval "$1"` and `eval "$2"` in `parallel`, but there must be a nicer way...

Comment: "Enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot" ... Thanks for the notice; edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running it without the '&' character? Usually the ampersand tells bash to run a command in the background and continue on to the next one. Without the ampersand the tasks should wait until completion to move on to the next one.

Michael G.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. shaklasah needs to run two jobs simultaneously; then wait for them both to finish; then run two more jobs. So the `&` is intentional and kind of necessary.

Comment: exactly @JasonOrendorff so what do u think should it be?!